# I changed organizations, but want to publish old work -- what should my affiliation be?

Tags: publications, affiliation

I used to do research (mostly computer science) at university *X*, including work on my master's thesis, parts of which I now want to publish.

However, I recently started working at another academic institution, university *Y*, where my research focus is slightly different – so there's no big topical overlap.

If I had submitted a paper a few months ago, I would have listed myself and my thesis supervisor as the authors, with my old affiliation of university *X*. But now, should I just change my affiliation to university *Y*? Would it be considered unethical to publish something that wasn't approved by them? (Even if I did it in my spare time?)

What is the recommended way to follow here?

Comment: There's also [Affiliation on a paper written mostly in previous position](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16866/affiliation-on-a-paper-written-mostly-in-previous-position)