# What affiliation to put on paper?

Tags: affiliation, biology, medicine

I finished my Master one year ago and now I am writing a paper from my master thesis. But now i am a PhD student in another university (another country). Which affiliation i should write in the paper?. Is it ok to write both university names on paper? 
Thanks

Comment: [Changing affiliation on publication](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11151/17254) is another relevant question.

Answer (score 1):

Put the current affiliation and make a comment in the title page (i.e., a footnote) stating "this work was conducted as part of a master's dissertation [in the older university]".