# Can I change my academic affiliation after a conference paper is accepted but before submitting the camera ready version?

Tags: publications, affiliation

My case is the following; I was doing independent research while I was working in a university, which, by the way I did not use any resource from that place of work at all. During the time I was at this university, a conference came up where I saw the possibility to submit my research, and because they asked for an academic affiliation to be put in the paper; I put the one of my then current work-place.

While I was waiting for a decision from the conference on whether my paper would be accepted, I got a part time job in another university. The good thing about this new place is that they have offered me that they would pay any expenses related to research publication. I know that they have not said that straightforward, but I suppose that they want me to put them as my academic affiliation.

Now the paper has got accepted, and I have to make the final version of it, so I was wondering if it would be possible that I can change my academic affiliation to the new place which has offered to pay the expenses for me?

Can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking if the conference will allow you to change your affiliation after the paper is accepted (but presumably, before you have submitted the camera ready version)? Or are you asking whether it's appropriate to list the new place as your affiliation?

Comment: the first one, because I still need to submit the camera ready version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to your comment, you are asking whether the conference will allow you to change your listed affiliation between acceptance and submission of the camera-ready version.

In my experience, the answer is **yes**. I have done this several times without issue. If there's no way to do this by yourself in the paper submission site, you can email the chair and ask him/her to update your information.

Whether you *should* use your new institution as your affiliation just to get them  to pay for your expenses is another issue entirely, which you have already asked about in [another question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/academic-affiliation-which-to-choose).