# How to deal with multiple affiliations as an author?

Tags: publications, authorship, affiliation

From the upcoming autumn on, I will be a tenured full-time professor at a regional university. In addition, I will have a 10% side job at an extramural research institution. And on top of that, I'll be an adjunct professor (only title and right to teach and act as thesis supervisor, no contract nor money) at another university.

My question is: What is the correct way to deal with these affiliations on potential publications?

The options I see are the following:

1. On each and every publication, I list all three affiliations. I am not completely comfortable with that, though, as the main draw of being a professor is independence - and in the 10% side job, I am of course not independent. Also, it's possibly questionable whether the other university should receive credit for having me as unpaid adjunct lecturer.
2. I always list my main affiliation (i.e. the university which pays my main salary), and add the other affiliations when this really applies (i.e. if a work is clearly the result of being affiliated with the respective organization).

Is there other options? Or anything in between? For my academic image, the combination of all three affiliations is certainly not a bad thing, but I feel putting something on my homepage, in my CV or in a public bio is probably different to assigning work outputs to organizations that pay or don't pay salaries.

Comment: Who is funding your research on your papers? Unlikely to be the one where you adjunct.

Comment: That's what I tried to say: The adjunct organization doesn't pay anything, but is a prestigious school. The university that provides me with tenure pays my research - and so does the external research institute - but only with respect to some clearly defined projects I contribute to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Academic affiliation: which to choose?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/academic-affiliation-which-to-choose)

Comment: you would be paid if you taught right?

Comment: Also, what are the downsides of listing institution #2? I don't see any

Comment: Some editors want to know all of your affiliations because it affects what peer reviewers they send your paper to.  It's especially important for grant review panels to make sure there isn't a bias (or a perception of bias)

Comment: @Buffy: Some papers will be funded by university #1, some by the external institute. None by university #2.

Comment: @AzorAhai: As an adjunct teaching professor in Germany, you don't get paid for teaching. And the downside of listing institution #2 (the external institute) is that publications have to be approved by the institute director, whereas as a university professor you can publish whatever you want without asking for anybody's permission.

Comment: @Michael If you're an adjunct teaching professor, what *do* you get paid to do? As for that, well that makes sense. But I imagine if they have strict rules on that sort of thing, they also do on whether or not you must list them.

Answer (score 9):

I'm professor at a university, which pays my bills, and I'm also affiliated with another institution, without any money involved. I do as in 2: I put always first my university affiliation and second the other affiliation for papers in collaboration.

It should be noted that in the recent past I had to fight with a journal because the copy editor arbitrarily changed the order of affiliations just to compact the list of affiliations.

Comment: Thanks for this asnwer. If I understand you correctly, you only put the other/second affiliation for those papers created in collaboration. For the other papers, it's just your main affiliation, right?

Comment: @Michael Yes, exactly. Note also that in my university the Department should approve any secondary affiliation, and messing up with the order of affiliations would not be seen favourably when asking permission for renewal.