# Publish papers with multiple affiliations

Tags: publications, affiliation

Somebody has two affiliations A and B. This person is paid and actually employed by affiliation A; not paid by B but honorarily employed by B. If this person publishes papers on math/phys fields, should affiliation B be put on the paper as well? Could this increase the chance of B employing this person in the future as a wild guess?

Comment: What is "honorarily employed"?

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/148367/20058

Comment: @BryanKrause somebody is a faculty member of somewhere but isn't paid by them, nor do they physically work there

Comment: Rerlated, possibly helpful: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/171418/etiquette-for-institutional-affiliation-if-you-changed-institutions-during-the-r/171446#171446

Comment: many thanks for all the suggestions answers. What I really care about is: Could this offer me any benefit or increase the chance of B employing this person in the future as a wild guess?